# stored procedure pattern match

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I have one table name as `DATA_TABLE`.

My Stored Procedure:

```
create or replace

PROCEDURE EXECUTE_CPROC    
( 
  CALLNUM IN VARCHAR2, 
  RESULT OUT VARCHAR2
)
AS    
vara_val NUMBER(1) ;    
varb_val NUMBER(1) ;   
BEGIN

     select a_val,b_val into vara_val, varb_val 
     from DATA_TABLE 
     where NumberPattern  like CALLNUM ||'%' ;

END
```

============

- Now if `CALLNUM` is 0335412 then in `DATA_TABLE` table `NumberPattern` 03354 should match.
- if `CALLNUM` is 033111 then in `DATA_TABLE` table `NumberPattern` 033 should match.

So need to modify the query written in SP.

============

Table Name : `DATA_TABLE`

Columns:

1. `NumberPattern` (varchar2) : 033, 03354
2. `a_val` ( integer ) : 1, 2
3. `b_val` ( integer ) : 1, 2

Comment: Let me know if question you have any doubt in question

Comment: I don't see the table `DATA_TABLE` in your query? How the table `DATA_TABLE` fits in the stored procedure and how it is relates to the other tables `cdiv_service_activation`, `vara_val`, `varb_val`?

Comment: But '03354' LIKE '0335412%' is false; it should be '0335412' LIKE '03354%' instead. Hence: `where CALLNUM like NumberPattern || '%' `. Apart from that I don't understand the question. There is `RESULT`, which you don't fill, and `vara_val` and `varb_val` which you fill but don't return. So what is your question actually?

Comment: @  Mahmoud Gamal : sorry its a copy paste mistake. Edited query now.

Comment: @Thorsten Kettner : 
 
I am facing one issue in this. In my call number CALLNUM is 03354123 then i m getting 2 results. 1) 03354123 like 033% 2) 03354123 like 03354%. Both are true so getting 2 results. I want that only 03354123 like 03354% should return. I mean max match pattern. Can you please help

Comment: So swapping CALLNUM and NumberPattern in your like clause fixes your query, right? But you can get several matches where you only want the largest. But what about my other comments? What is it about `vara_val` and `varb_val` you are selecting but not using at all? What value(s) is your procedure supposed to return? The longest matching NumberPattern? Or another or several other columns from the record where the longest matching NumberPattern  resides in? Please clarify.

Comment: @Thorsten Kettner  : Thanks. I asked it here and got the guidance. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33251452/stored-procedure-maximum-pattern-match/33251934?noredirect=1#comment54307091_33251934

Comment: Well, I don't think this was worth a new question; you could have altered this one. And still your other request has the same flaws, showing a procedure that does virtually nothing, because it doesn't return anything from the query used. I am glad you got your answer there, though. Please accept Bob's answer here, because he answered you how to find matches, which was more or less the question you had.

Comment: @Thorsten Kettner : Procedure i have written in the question is not full. I have copied only the half of the procedure which relates to the question. This is the reason it seems not returning anything. I have intentionally not copied full procedure to avoid complexity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query should be

```
 select a_val, b_val
   into vara_val, varb_val 
   from DATA_TABLE 
   where CALLNUM LIKE NumberPattern || '%';
```

You had `CALLNUM` and `NumberPattern` reversed in the query.

Best of luck.

Comment: Yes, I thought it is not correct to write : where CALLNUM LIKE NumberPattern || '%'; .  My understanding was after where it should be column name.

Comment: I am facing one issue in this. In my call number CALLNUM is 03354123 then i m getting 2 results. 1) 03354123 like 033% 2) 03354123 like 03354%. Both are true so getting 2 results. I want that only 03354123 like 03354% should return. I mean max match pattern. Can you please help.